# Spark lag function with parameter as dynamic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement the lag function in spark; which I was able to do like below
(with some data from hive/temp spark table)

Say the DF has these rows:

```
lagno:value
0, 100
0, 200
2, null
3, null
```

where the first column is the actual lag number which you want to use, and the second column is actual value.

When I run this query it works:

```
DataFrame df;
DataFrame dfnew=df.select(
            org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag( df.col("value"), 1 ).over(org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(new1.col("value"))));
```

that means if hard code the value of lag no, it works fine.

However, if I pass the lag value as a parameter it's not working:

```
DataFrame dfnew=df.select(
            org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lag( df.col("value"),df.col("lagno").over(org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(new1.col("value"))));
```

Do I need to type cast the parameter of col type to integer?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Window functions use fixed size frames that cannot be dynamically modified. You can compute `lag` for `1..3` and then select one required for the current row.

```
CASE 
  WHEN lagno = 1 THEN LAG(value,  1) OVER w 
  WHEN lagno = 2 THEN LAG(value,  2) OVER w 
  ...
  ELSE value
END
```

Comment: @LostlnOverflow..yeah.. i did the same with case ..since my lagno is expecting more than 50 i might end up writing 50 conditions..Is there any way a can have a UDF which shall take the lgno col value and returns integer.. but i am tentative if this can be possible.