# How to calculate rolling sum with varying window sizes in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that contains sales prediction data for some products in some stores over a time period. How do I calculate the rolling sum of Predictions for a window size of next N values?

**Input Data**

```
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+
| ProductId | StoreId |    Date    | Prediction | N |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-01 | 0.92       | 2 |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-02 | 0.62       | 2 |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-03 | 0.89       | 2 |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-04 | 0.57       | 2 |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-01 | 1.39       | 3 |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-02 | 1.22       | 3 |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-03 | 1.33       | 3 |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-04 | 1.61       | 3 |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+
```

**Expected Output Data**

```
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+------------------------+
| ProductId | StoreId |    Date    | Prediction | N |       RollingSum       |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+------------------------+
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-01 | 0.92       | 2 | sum(0.92, 0.62)        |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-02 | 0.62       | 2 | sum(0.62, 0.89)        |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-03 | 0.89       | 2 | sum(0.89, 0.57)        |
|         1 |     100 | 2019-07-04 | 0.57       | 2 | sum(0.57)              |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-01 | 1.39       | 3 | sum(1.39, 1.22, 1.33)  |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-02 | 1.22       | 3 | sum(1.22, 1.33, 1.61 ) |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-03 | 1.33       | 3 | sum(1.33, 1.61)        |
|         2 |     200 | 2019-07-04 | 1.61       | 3 | sum(1.61)              |
+-----------+---------+------------+------------+---+------------------------+
```

There are lots of questions and answers to this problem in Python but I couldn't find any in PySpark.

**Similar Question 1** 
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767807/how-to-calculate-rolling-median-in-pyspark-using-window) but in this one frame size is fixed to 3. In the provided answer rangeBetween function is used and it is only working with fixed sized frames so I cannot use it for varying sizes.

**Similar Question 2** 
There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522074/spark-lag-function-with-parameter-as-dynamic). In this one, writing cases for all possible sizes is suggested but it is not applicable for my case since I don't know how many distinct frame sizes I need to calculate.

**Solution attempt 1** 
I've tried to solve the problem using a pandas udf:

```
rolling_sum_predictions = predictions.groupBy('ProductId', 'StoreId').apply(calculate_rolling_sums)
```

*calculate_rolling_sums* is a pandas udf where I solve the problem in python. This solution works with a small amount of test data. However, when the data gets bigger (in my case, the input df has around 1B rows), calculations take so long.

**Solution attempt 2** 
I have used a workaround of the answer of *Similar Question 1* above. I've calculated the biggest possible N, created the list using it and then calculate the sum of predictions by slicing the list.

```
predictions = predictions.withColumn('DayIndex', F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('ProductId', 'StoreId').orderBy('Date')))

# find the biggest period
biggest_period = predictions.agg({"N": "max"}).collect()[0][0]

# calculate rolling predictions starting from the DayIndex
w = (Window.partitionBy(F.col("ProductId"), F.col("StoreId")).orderBy(F.col('DayIndex')).rangeBetween(0, biggest_period - 1))
rolling_prediction_lists = predictions.withColumn("next_preds", F.collect_list("Prediction").over(w))

# calculate rolling forecast sums
pred_sum_udf = udf(lambda preds, period: float(np.sum(preds[:period])), FloatType())
rolling_pred_sums = rolling_prediction_lists \
    .withColumn("RollingSum", pred_sum_udf("next_preds", "N"))
```

This solution is also works with the test data. I couldn't have chance to test it with the original data yet but whether it works or not I do not like this solution. Is there any smarter way to solve this?

Comment: What version of spark? If it's 2.4+ you can use [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=slice#pyspark.sql.functions.slice) instead of `udf` and you don't need to get the `biggest_period` - you can use `Window.unboundedFollowing`.

Comment: My Spark version is 2.4.3

Comment: I can't test right now but try this: first collect the predictions from the current row on using `df = df.withColumn("PredList", collect_list("Prediction").over(Window.partitionBy("ProductId", "StoreId").orderBy("Date").rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)))` then use [`expr` to pass a column value as a arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function) to `slice`: `df = df.withColumn("RollingSum", expr("slice(PredList, 1, N)"))` - you can add a `sum` to the last step if that's what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using spark 2.4+, you can use the new [higher-order array functions](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-2.4.0-features-array-higher-order-functions/read) `slice` and `aggregate` to efficiently implement your requirement without any UDFs:

```
summed_predictions = predictions\
   .withColumn("summed", F.collect_list("Prediction").over(Window.partitionBy("ProductId", "StoreId").orderBy("Date").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing))\
   .withColumn("summed", F.expr("aggregate(slice(summed,1,N), cast(0 as double), (acc,d) -> acc + d)"))

summed_predictions.show()
+---------+-------+-------------------+----------+---+------------------+
|ProductId|StoreId|               Date|Prediction|  N|            summed|
+---------+-------+-------------------+----------+---+------------------+
|        1|    100|2019-07-01 00:00:00|      0.92|  2|              1.54|
|        1|    100|2019-07-02 00:00:00|      0.62|  2|              1.51|
|        1|    100|2019-07-03 00:00:00|      0.89|  2|              1.46|
|        1|    100|2019-07-04 00:00:00|      0.57|  2|              0.57|
|        2|    200|2019-07-01 00:00:00|      1.39|  3|              3.94|
|        2|    200|2019-07-02 00:00:00|      1.22|  3|              4.16|
|        2|    200|2019-07-03 00:00:00|      1.33|  3|2.9400000000000004|
|        2|    200|2019-07-04 00:00:00|      1.61|  3|              1.61|
+---------+-------+-------------------+----------+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Apparently not: `cannot resolve 'sum(slice(`avg`, 1, `N`))' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not array<double>`

Comment: Thank you rluta and @pault. This version works and performs much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best, but you can get distinct "N" column values and loop like below.

```
val arr = df.select("N").distinct.collect

for(n <- arr) df.filter(col("N") ===  n.get(0))
.withColumn("RollingSum",sum(col("Prediction"))
.over(Window.partitionBy("N").orderBy("N").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, n.get(0).toString.toLong-1))).show
```

This will give you like:

```
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+------------------+
|ProductId|StoreId|      Date|Prediction|  N|        RollingSum|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+------------------+
|        2|    200|2019-07-01|      1.39|  3|              3.94|
|        2|    200|2019-07-02|      1.22|  3|              4.16|
|        2|    200|2019-07-03|      1.33|  3|2.9400000000000004|
|        2|    200|2019-07-04|      1.61|  3|              1.61|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+------------------+

+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+----------+
|ProductId|StoreId|      Date|Prediction|  N|RollingSum|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+----------+
|        1|    100|2019-07-01|      0.92|  2|      1.54|
|        1|    100|2019-07-02|      0.62|  2|      1.51|
|        1|    100|2019-07-03|      0.89|  2|      1.46|
|        1|    100|2019-07-04|      0.57|  2|      0.57|
+---------+-------+----------+----------+---+----------+
```

Then you can do a union of all the dataframes inside the loop.