# PySpark: applying varying window sizes to a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

I have a spark dataframe that looks something like below.

| date | ID | window_size | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 02/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 03/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 04/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 01/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 02/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 03/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 04/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I'm trying to apply a rolling window of size window_size to each ID in the dataframe and get the rolling sum. Basically I'm calculating a rolling sum (`pd.groupby.rolling(window=n).sum()` in pandas) where the window size (n) can change per group.

**Expected output**

| date | ID | window_size | qty | rolling_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | null |
| 02/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 03/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 04/01/2020 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 01/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 1 | null |
| 02/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 2 | null |
| 03/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 04/01/2020 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9 |

I'm struggling to find a solution that works and is fast enough on a large dataframe (+- 350M rows).

**What I have tried**

I tried the solution in the below [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551807/how-to-calculate-rolling-sum-with-varying-window-sizes-in-pyspark):

The idea is to first use `sf.collect_list` and then slice the `ArrayType` column correctly.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as st
import pyspark.sql.function as sf

window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(params['date'])

output = (
    sdf
    .withColumn("qty_list", sf.collect_list('qty').over(window))
    .withColumn("count", sf.count('qty').over(window))
    .withColumn("rolling_sum", sf.when(sf.col('count') < sf.col('window_size'), None)
                                 .otherwise(sf.slice('qty_list', sf.col('count'), sf.col('window_size'))))
).show()
```

However this yields below error:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

I have also tried using `sf.expr` like below

```
window = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(params['date'])

output = (
    sdf
    .withColumn("qty_list", sf.collect_list('qty').over(window))
    .withColumn("count", sf.count('qty').over(window))
    .withColumn("rolling_sum", sf.when(sf.col('count') < sf.col('window_size'), None)
                                 .otherwise(sf.expr("slice('window_size', 'count', 'window_size')")))
).show()
```

Which yields:

> data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however,
> ''qty_list'' is of string type.; line 1 pos 0;

I tried manually casting the `qty_list` column to `ArrayType(IntegerType())` with the same result.

I tried using a UDF but that fails with several out of memory errors after 1,5 hours or so.

**Questions**

1. Reading the spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.slice.html) suggests to me that I should be able to pass columns to `sf.slice()`, am I doing something wrong? Where is the `TypeError` coming from?
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I want without using `sf.collect_list()` and/or `sf.slice()`?
3. If all else fails, what would be the optimal way to do this using a udf? I attempted different versions of the same udf and tried to make sure the udf is the last operation spark has to perform, but all failed.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of `window_size` and how you get your output?

Comment: window_size defines the rolling window size, which can vary per ID. So I need the rolling sum but the window definition can change for each ID in the dataframe. I'm getting my output by simply using .show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the errors you get:

1. The first one means you can't pass a column to `slice` using DataFrame API function (unless you have Spark [3.1+](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32338)). But you already got it as you tried using it within SQL expression.
2. Second error occurs because you pass column names quoted in your `expr`. It should be `slice(qty_list, count, window_size)` otherwise Spark is considering them as strings hence the error message.

That said, you almost got it, you need to change the expression for slicing to get the correct size of array, then use `aggregate` function to sum up the values of the resulting array. Try with this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')

output = df.withColumn("qty_list", F.collect_list('qty').over(w)) \
    .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .withColumn(
        "qty_list",
        F.when(
            F.col('rn') < F.col('window_size'),
            None
        ).otherwise(F.expr("slice(qty_list, rn-window_size+1, window_size)"))
    ).withColumn(
        "rolling_sum",
        F.expr("aggregate(qty_list, 0D, (acc, x) -> acc + x)").cast("int")
    ).drop("qty_list", "rn")

output.show()
#+----------+---+-----------+---+-----------+
#|      date| ID|window_size|qty|rolling_sum|
#+----------+---+-----------+---+-----------+
#|01/01/2020|  1|          2|  1|       null|
#|02/01/2020|  1|          2|  2|          3|
#|03/01/2020|  1|          2|  3|          5|
#|04/01/2020|  1|          2|  4|          7|
#|01/01/2020|  2|          3|  1|       null|
#|02/01/2020|  2|          3|  2|       null|
#|03/01/2020|  2|          3|  3|          6|
#|04/01/2020|  2|          3|  4|          9|
#+----------+---+-----------+---+-----------+
```